# SSIS 2008 Server iteration connection error (validation)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2008

I'm having to write an SSIS package in 2008 using BIDS and have a simple foreach loop that reads a list of servers and DBs from a database and then iterates over them running various data flows.

The problem I'm running into is one of verification - I've set `Delayed Validation = true` wherever I need to but whenever any part of the OLEDB Source changes (having it's connection set dynamically via the foreach) it insists on revalidating the connection. This means that every time the code changes I have to create a new connection and then set the Expressions again for server and database. I've recreated the package in 2013 using SQL Data Tools and can quite happily use a single database connection with properties set in all the data flows.

Is this is a known limitation in 2008 or am I doing something wrong?

**edit to make the question clearer**

I'm not changing anything at runtime except the properties of the connection as it cycles through the list of servers and databases to connect to. The problem is in the designer as it will not stop trying to validate the connection. So, for example, in SSIS 2013+ I have connection properties set dynamically and if I change the underlying data call I switch to a non dynamic connection, update the columns and metadata etc then switch back to my dynamic connection. No problem at all. In 2008 when I switch back to the dynamic connection it won't validate (as the expressions are set at runtime) and I have to actually set up a new connection, then set it's properties by expression and it's happy. Obviously as I'm developing and testing this is a PITA. Hope this is a bit clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by `whenever any part of the OLEDB Source changes`? Are Source Table structures the same or they have different columns?

Comment: If I edit the SQL or just actually interact with the OLEDB Data Source it revalidated the connection, which then fails as the properties are set via expressions. Delayed validation seems to have no effect.

Comment: A given data flow in SSIS cannot have it's metadata (columns, data types) changed at runtime. That's just the way it works.

Comment: @bhs as Nick mentioned, you can only use dynamic connections if **all tables has the same structure.**

Comment: I'll add a comment to the question to make myself clearer

Comment: @bhs Try changing the ValidateExternalMetadata to False in the OLEDB SOURCE

Comment: @bhs also check that `Delayed Validation = true` property is set on the Data Flow Task and on the OLEDB Connection manager

Comment: thanks guys - the infrastructure guys have given the green light for 2016 so SSDT (where there is no problem) is the tool I'll use - a fond farewell to 2008 and BIDS ;-)